# Housekeeping on history table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure in which I save in a historic table the data from another table. However, I do not want my historic table to get too big and would like to do remove the entries which are older than 1 week. What would be the best approach to achieve this?

```
INSERT INTO table_h
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        table;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Without knowing the fields you have in TABLE_H there's no way to answer this. HOPEFULLY you have an ADD_DATE field or similar which you can use to purge the table.

Comment: @banana_99 Are you licensed for partitioning? It's an extra-cost option within Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson how I can check that?

Comment: If your system is already using partitioning then you are probably OK. Otherwise ask your DBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, an approach is to use `delete` with a `where` clause:

```
delete from t
    where datecol < trunc(sysdate) - interval '7' day;
```

The best approach, though, is probably to partition the table by weeks (or days).  Then drop partitions as they get older.  Dropping a partition is generally much faster than deleting individual records.

Comment: Thanks. How can I partition by weeks?

Comment: @banana_99 . . . The place to start is in the documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/vldbg/partition-concepts.html#GUID-EA7EF5CB-DD49-43AF-889A-F83AAC0D7D51.